# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result - Cant add multiple strings in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I understand that this issue has been posted before but I'm having a slightly different issue.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM $sql_table WHERE make LIKE '%$make%' OR WHERE model LIKE '$model'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (!'result') {
    echo "<p class=\"wrong\">Something is wrong with ", $query, "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n "
        . "<th scope=\"col\">Make</th>\n "
        . "<th scope=\"col\">Model</th>\n "
        . "<th scope=\"col\">Price</th>\n "
        . "<th scope=\"col\">YOM</th>\n "
        . "</tr>\n ";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>\n ",
        "<td>", $row['make'], "</td>\n ",
        "<td>", $row['model'], "</td>\n ",
        "<td>", $row['price'], "</td>\n ",
        "<td>", $row['yom'], "</td>\n ";
        echo "</tr>\n ";
    }
}
```

My code works when I have a string such as make, where it returns all cars with that certain make. But when I try to add to the string so I can return more results based on the search, it is returning the above error. I'm not sure how I should be adding together these strings in the SQL Query.

Comment: Bind variables to your query! Don't use string concatenation AT ALL, it leads to SQL injection, and causes errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query syntax as;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE make LIKE '%$make%' OR model LIKE '$model'"
```

you can not use two where clause in one query.